# What is the best remote desktop tool to connect to Windows from Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I've used [rdesktop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rdesktop/files/) in the past.  Is there something better?

Comment: With 11.10, `tsclient` is no longer ships. Instead the Remote Desktop Viewer, or Vinagre, now supports RDP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu ships by default with tsclient. It works pretty well for me.

Comment: I find it's not as polished as the windows equivalent. Remote desktop feels much better on the windows remote desktop tool.

Comment: @levesque It's just a frontend for `rdesktop`, so if you use that, you're getting basically the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

You can try remmina. While it uses the same backend as tsclient and friends (the backend being rdesktop). It has a more pleasing UI when compared to tsclient.

Comment: I use Remmina since it allows me to control the depth of colour easily - I found this made a HUGE performance improvement (using a low colour depth of 256 colours) when remote controlling a computer in New Zealand from Australia. Really was unusable using Remote Desktop Viewer, although if you know how, you can probably control the colour depth with all of them. Remmina made it easy.

Answer (score 5):

### rdesktop

rdesktop is an open source client for Windows NT/2000 Terminal Server and  Windows Server 2003/2008. Capable of natively speaking its Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) in order to present the user's Windows desktop. Unlike Citrix ICA, no server extensions are required.

To install rdesktop in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install rdesktop
```

A typical command looks like this.

```
rdesktop 192.168.1.23 -k de -g 1500x1150  -r disk:mydisk=/home/soma
```

**Parameters:**

```
-k de............................ set keyboard layout
-g 1500x1........................ set resolution of the rdesktop window
-r disk:mydisk=/home/soma.........share your home directory with the remote machine
```

Answer (score 3):

KRDC, which comes as part of Kubuntu, allows better control of the appearance of the remote window than just using rdesktop or tsclient.  In particular, it allows a full screen view that you can minimise, unlike the other two, which (as far as I can tell) require you to log out to return to your Ubuntu session if you are using full screen.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)?

Comment: yeah, Teamviewer is good but it needs to be running on both the computers, I wanted something which was closer to "RDP"

Answer (score 2):

Although TightVNC 2 does not have a Linux version, you can still get the old version (1.3.10) [here](http://www.tightvnc.com/download-old.php#stable).

I have used TightVNC before and it is quite fast. (Of course, I do it the other way around - I log into my Ubuntu box from Windows.)

Comment: Although TightVNC or any VNC doesnt really compair to remote desktop it is probably a good method.  There are just things vnc can't to that remote desktop does.

Comment: @Walter, such as?

Answer (score 2):

'rdesktop' seems to work pretty well in general. If you miss ClearType fonts (like I do), then this might solve your problem:

http://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2008/03/10/rdesktop-connect-to-windows-vista-with-cleartype-font-smoothing-enabled/

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the server side, I suggest installing and using Real VNC - http://www.realvnc.com/

Answer (score 2):

gnome-rdp is available in the ubuntu repositories. It supports RDP, VNC and SSH protocols and allows you to configure and store multiple sessions.