# What to use to connect to nomachine's server?

Tags: remote-desktop

I was told to use [nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php) to access a remote server.

Is there anything else that I could use instead?

The remote server is already running the nomachine's server application. 
I would like to use an application supported by Ubuntu (for nomachine's package I had to enable a PPA, using the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX)).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/352/what-is-the-best-remote-desktop-tool-to-connect-to-windows-from-ubuntu

Comment: @belacqua I'd say no, it's not a duplicate, primarily because that question is Ubuntu > Windows, this is Ubuntu > * (or vice versa).

Comment: If it was a duplicate, now it is not. And as jrg mentioned, the other question asks specifically to connect to a window's desktop.

Comment: No problem with duplicates (if all answers everywhere are great, we should merge them) -- just thinking there might be a lot of overlap.

Comment: I can see some overlap, since it was suggested I think a merger is a good idea.

Comment: There is overlap (some clients handle multiple things and the core idea is the same) but I'm thinking of people who might be searching for something specific like "ubuntu nomachine clients" or "ubuntu rdp clients". Keeping RDP, VNC, XDCMP, NX, etc separate would benefit them and make each list of answers more maintainable.

Comment: @Oli Fair enough!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [remmina](http://packages.ubuntu.com/remmina) [image: Install remmina]

Remmina is a remote desktop client written in GTK+, aiming to be useful for system administrators and travellers, who need to work with lots of remote computers in front of either large monitors or tiny netbooks. Remmina supports multiple network protocols in an integrated and consistant user interface. Currently RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH are supported.

Remmina is released in separated source packages:

```
 "remmina", the main GTK+ application
 "remmina-plugins", a set of plugins
 "remmina-gnome", the GNOME desktop applet
 "remmina-xfce", the Xfce panel plugin
```

Remmina is free and open-source software, released under GNU GPL license.

screenshots : [here](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

### Xrdp

`xrdp` is the Remote Desktop Protocol to the X window system

Install [Xrdp](http://apt%3axrdp%22Xrdp%22)

Use the terminal server client to connect.

Comment: OP explicitly asks how to connect to a (nomachine) NX server. Xrdp does not do this.

Comment: @Jan that was AFTER he edited the question